# Pasar valor a otra clase

Tags: java

tengo en una clase llamada Entrada el siguiente programa:

```
public class Entrada {

    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{

        Scanner lector = new Scanner (System.in);
        String fichero ;            
        System.out.println("Posa el nom del ficher:");
        fichero = lector.nextLine();
        File file = new File(fichero); 
        EscriureLlibreria(fichero);


    }
```

Como puedo pasar el valor fichero a la clase Sortida?

```
    public class Sortida {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

 try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Llibreria.class);
        Unmarshaller ums = context.createUnmarshaller();
        // Mostrem el fitcher creat previament a la clase Entrada.
        Entrada.EscriureLlibreria(fichero);
        JAXBElement<Llibre> rootElementCast = ums.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new File(fichero)), Llibre.class);

        //Mostrem totes les característiques que hem demanat per teclat.
        Llibre llibreria = rootElementCast.getValue();
            System.out.println("Autor:" + llibreria.getAutor());
            System.out.println("Nom" + llibreria.getNom());
            System.out.println("Editorial" + llibreria.getEditorial());
            System.out.println("ISBN:" + llibreria.getIsbn());
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
}
        }
}
```

Con valor fichero me refieroa dentro de Public Class Entrada {
dentro del main consigo un valor que es el de fichero.

El valor es que me da un fichero entrado por el usuario, pues ese valor lo quiero en :

public class Sortida{

dentro de su main para usarlo para leerlo.

algo asi:

Entrada.EscriureLlibreria(**fichero**);
        JAXBElement rootElementCast = ums.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new File(**fichero**)), Llibre.class);

Comment: ¿Tu código se quedó truncado en la pregunta? El bloque `try` no se completa y por consiguiente la clase `Sortida` tampoco.   Para pasar el valor `fichero` la clase `Sortida` debe tener: **A.** Un parámetro del constructor que lo acepte, entonces lo puedes pasar al crear la instancia de la clase: `sortida=new Sortida(fichero, otros, posibles, parametros);`. O bien, **B.** Un método que lo acepte, entonces le pasas el valor `fichero` a ese método para manejar el valor dentro de él: `sortida = new Sortida();  sortida.metodoManejarFichero(fichero);`

Comment: Hola, no he puesto todo el programa por que no lo veía necesario.. Es decir el valor "fichero" lo necesito dentro del main en la parte de ums.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new File(file))

Comment: lo edito y pongo todo el programa.

Comment: @A.Cedano espero que ahora este más claro!

Comment: Me pregunto por qué tienes dos clases con el método `Main`. Creo que tienes un problema de organización de tu aplicación. Por lógica, `Main` debe estar sólo en `Entrada` (lo digo por el nombre de la clase, pues `Main` es precisamente el punto de entrada de toda aplicación Java) y si quieres llamar a `Sortida` la instancias desde allí. Actualmente tienes la entrada de la `Entrada` y tienes la entrada también en la `Sortida` ¿cómo es eso?

Comment: Por que en mi colegio me piden "2 programas" en uno.. Es decir por una parte ENTRADA y en otra SALIDA.  pero ambos juntos en el mismo paquete.
Es decir en ENTRADA crea un fichero. y en SALIDA lee el fichero creado en ENTRADA.